# dynamic id to textbox

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am creating dynamic textbox and button in codeigniter view page through foreach loop. Then I want to retrieve the value of those **textboxes** on **buttton** click. please help me. Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter and attach the counter at end of textbox names so that dynamically created textboxes have names like textbox1, textbox2 etc. In controller's submit function run the loop again and fetch the values.

Regards

iijb